# Cloud Function running code that don't match with UI active code

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Cloud Function scheduled with Cloud Scheduler and Pub/Sub, running in a daily basis. The function just writes some rows to a database. Last week I added some code in the last lines to write to my database the number of rows written by the function, and the date of these writes. I deployed the function and is working fine (today I saw the row inserted by today's execution).

Problem is that today when I tried to edit the function through the UI, there isn't the code added last week (mentioned before). It seems like the function is running the last code successfully deployed, but the UI is showing a previous version. Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you download the source using the Download Zip button, is it still the old code?

Comment: @OliverAragon Yes, source in Download Zip is the same source that is showed in the UI (the old code)

Comment: I would suggest to open a new ticket on console.cloud.google.com/support as this seems to require further inspection of the project as it looks to be an internal issue

Comment: @OliverAragon it was a bug on their side (posted in my answer), thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug:

> Hello Google Cloud Customer,
>
> We have discovered that on May 8, 2020, from approximately 03:38 until
>   15:04 PDT (10:38 - 22:04 UTC), updated metadata for create and update
>   operations executed on Cloud Functions in the us-central1, us-east1,
>   and us-east4 regions were lost.
>
> Function metadata refers to configuration about the function, which
>   includes: version information, last update time, memory allocation,
>   ingress/egress settings, trigger information, and configured
>   environment variables. If changes were made to that information during
>   the affected window, then those changes were lost.
>
> If you attempted to create or update functions during this window,
>   then your function may be experiencing one of these failure modes:
>
> Your function is executing a stale version; or Your function is
>   executing the latest version, but its state may be reflected
>   inaccurately in the Cloud Console (e.g., a function created/updated
>   during the time of the incident would be operational, however it would
>   not appear on the console).
>
> We recommend that customers re-deploy the functions listed above,
>   which will reconcile the state of these functions.
>
> Any successful deployment will result in a successful reconciliation
>   of the metadata. If changes were made to ingress/egress settings or
>   environment variables, we recommend that you make those changes again.
>
> We sincerely apologize for the inconvenience this issue has caused. If
>   you require assistance with an impacted function, please reply to this
>   email to contact Google Cloud Support.